# branch and cut optimal solution guaranteed

Tags: optimization

Is "Branch and cut" method guaranteed to obtain an optimal solution? if not, under what conditions it would be guaranteed. is there a reference that I could refer to (a paper would be great)?
thanks

Comment: It should - it's better than branch and bound if I recall correctly.

Comment: @SeanRoberson [Branch and cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_cut) seems to be the specialization of branch and bound for integer programming. Cut means throwing away a part of the search tree and of the feasible set with linear inequalities, usable in the linear programming relaxation used to bound the optimal solution of a given subtree (subset of solutions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly implemented (meaning that it correctly detects infeasible and suboptimal nodes, and correctly partitions non-terminal nodes), given a feasible and bounded problem with a finite integer search space, and given enough time and memory, yes, branch and cut guarantees finding an optimal solution. The logic is the same as for branch and bound: the search tree has a finite number of nodes, so eventually you run out of nodes, at which point the best detected feasible solution is the winner.

Comment: Thank you, prubin. Is there a refference paper that you can think off which states this fact? A book could do it.  I need to properly reference this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help there. The books in my library are too old to even mention branch and cut.